# Should the "difference" and "meaning" tags be used together?

Tags: discussion, tags

The excerpt for [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) says (after the pending edit is approved):

> This tag is for questions about the difference in meaning between certain words, or phrases.

The tag is already supposed to be about the difference in meaning between words, or phrases, but I see some of the questions are also using [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). (There are 28 questions tagged [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference), and [6 questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference+meaning) using [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) and [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).)

Does it make sense to use both the tag for a question? [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) says the question is about the difference in meaning, and [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) says the question is about the meaning of a word/phrase/sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the tag wiki is quite incorrect. The [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) tag is not limited to [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). It can be of [tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses), [pronunciation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation), and so forth. My (suggested) version of the [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) tag is this:

```
This tag is for questions that asks about differences in usage of English.
```

So if we want to denote a question that asks about the differences in meaning, we can use both [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) and [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) at the same time. If we want to ask about differences in pronunciation, we can then use [pronunciation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) and [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) together.